# Windows phone How can I detect an incoming call

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, incoming-call

I have a app that runs a AudioPlaybackAgent and I want that everytime the phone receive a call, the audio get paused, but i didn't found anything about that.

Comment: Sorry there are no events that fire when a call comes in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Background Audio Manager, Phone will automatically Pause the playback and once call is disconnected it will automatically start playing.